# Importing Data with unpredictable filename using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to create a Integration Package in SSIS to loading data to SQL database from file that generate daily with the filename format "AAA_YYYYMMDDXXXXXX". I know how to use the variable function to generate the file name with time stamp but I don't know how to deal with the "XXXXXX" which is 6 unpredictable numbers different every time.

I tried to pick the most recent file but it doesn't work because there are other files in the same folder that updated daily can cause loading wrong data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for each loop to process the directory and have an expression set up on your filename. Since you know the date will be the same and are just worried about the final XXXXX characters you can use a wildcard.

Variable with an expression to generate the filename:

```
"AAA" + (DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(GETDATE() ) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH(GETDATE()), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(GETDATE()) , 2) + "*.csv"
```

Once your variable is configured set up an expression on the FileSpec property equal to your variable. Now the package will loop and only grab files that are from the most recent day

[image: For each loop config]

Within the for each loop you can then build your dataflow to load the file to the database.

Comment: This will match AAA_20180131XXXXXX.csv, AAA_20180131.csv as well as   AAA_YYYYMMDD_REALLYLONGBITSOFGIBBERISH.csv Whether that is a condition the user needs to account for is a different question. If they wish to filter for only 6 unpredictable characters, use a `?` to specify each character so the final bit of your expression would become "??????.csv"

Comment: Nice tip! I didn't know about the ? to limit to a specific number of characters.